# Swift4, JSON, keyNotFound, No value associated with key

Tags: json, swift4, codable

I need to do Sunset Sunrise App, and this is my code. But I have this error:

> Error serializing json: keyNotFound(Sunrise_Sunset.SunPosition.Results.(CodingKeys in _B4291256871B16D8D013EC8806040532).sunrise, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key sunrise (\"sunrise\").", underlyingError: nil))

And I don't understand how to fix it. Maybe someone had this problem. I will be grateful for any help)
This is the API, which I have: https://sunrise-sunset.org/api

```
struct SunPosition: Codable {
struct Results: Codable {
    let sunrise: String
    let sunset: String
    let solarNoon: String
    let dayLenght: String
    let civilTwilightBegin: String
    let civilTwilightEnd: String
    let nauticalTwilightBegin: String
    let nauticalTwilightEnd: String
    let astronomicalTwilightBegin: String
    let astronomicalTwilightEnd: String

    enum CodingKey:String, Swift.CodingKey {
        case sunrise = "sunrise"
        case sunset = "sunset"
        case solarNoon = "solar_noon"
        case dayLenght = "day_length"
        case civilTwilightBegin = "civil_twilight_begin"
        case civilTwilightEnd = "civil_twilight_end"
        case nauticalTwilightBegin = "nautical_twilight_begin"
        case nauticalTwilightEnd = "nautical_twilight_end"
        case astronomicalTwilightBegin = "astronomical_twilight_begin"
        case astronomicalTwilightEnd = "astronomical_twilight_end"
    }
  }
}

extension SunPosition.Results {
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    sunrise = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .sunrise)
    sunset = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .sunset)
    solarNoon = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .solarNoon)
    dayLenght = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .dayLenght)
    civilTwilightBegin = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .civilTwilightBegin)
    civilTwilightEnd = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .civilTwilightEnd)
    nauticalTwilightBegin = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .nauticalTwilightBegin)
    nauticalTwilightEnd = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .nauticalTwilightEnd)
    astronomicalTwilightBegin = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .astronomicalTwilightBegin)
    astronomicalTwilightEnd = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .astronomicalTwilightEnd)
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let sunPosition = try JSONDecoder().decode(SunPosition.Results.self, from: data)
            print(sunPosition)
        }catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }

    }.resume()
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Four issues:

1. Add `let results : Results` in the `SunPosition` struct.
2. Typo: `private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey` rather than `enum CodingKey :String, Swift.CodingKey`, note the singular / plural difference, the `private` attribute is recommended but does not cause the issue.
3. Wrong type to decode: `JSONDecoder().decode(SunPosition.self, from: data)` rather than `JSONDecoder().decode(SunPosition.Results.self, from: data)`.
4. To get the `results` you have to `print(sunPosition.results)`.

Three notes:

1. Delete the entire extension. In this case you get the initializer for free.
2. Add `&formatted=0` to the URL and set the `dateDecodingStrategy` of the decoder to `.iso8601` to get `Date` objects. Change the type of all date related properties from `String` to `Date` and the type of `dayLenght` from `String` to `TimeInterval`. To change `dateDecodingStrategy` write

   ```
   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
   decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
   let sunPosition = try decoder.decode(SunPosition.self ...
   ```
3. I recommend to handle the `status`, too. Add this in the `SunPosition` struct

   ```
   let status : String

   var success : Bool { return status == "OK" }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the error with "Sunrise", but now I have this error: 

Error serializing json: keyNotFound(Sunrise_Sunset.SunPosition.Results.(CodingKeys in _B4291256871B16D8D013EC8806040532).solarNoon, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Sunrise_Sunset.SunPosition.(CodingKeys in _B4291256871B16D8D013EC8806040532).results], debugDescription: "No value associated with key solarNoon (\"solarNoon\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Could you show me how and where, I can write dateDecodingStrategy ?

Comment: Now I get this error: 
Error serializing json: typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Sunrise_Sunset.SunPosition.(CodingKeys in _B4291256871B16D8D013EC8806040532).results, Sunrise_Sunset.SunPosition.Results.(CodingKeys in _B4291256871B16D8D013EC8806040532).sunrise], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: *Sigh* It's all described in the answer: *Change the type ... of `dayLenght` from `String` to `TimeInterval`*

Comment: But I changed:

`struct SunPosition: Codable{
    let results: Results
    struct Results: Codable {
        let sunrise: Date
        let sunset: Date
        let solarNoon: Date
        let dayLenght: TimeInterval
        let civilTwilightBegin: Date
        let civilTwilightEnd: Date
        let nauticalTwilightBegin: Date
        let nauticalTwilightEnd: Date
        let astronomicalTwilightBegin: Date
        let astronomicalTwilightEnd: Date`

Comment: And you added `&formatted=0` to the URL? I'm using that API for years and just updated the parsing to `Codable` myself. Everything is supposed to work.

Comment: Yes, I added
`let jsonUrlString = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400&formatted=0"`

Comment: Paste the URL in a browser and watch the result. What is the value for key `day_length`? I tested your entire code successfully in a Playground.

Comment: In the browser, I get this value :
day_length":35379

Comment: That's correct. I don't understand the error. There is no string where a double is expected. I run again exactly your code with my changes. It's working.

Comment: I don't understand too, but thank you very much for your help

Comment: Wait a minute, did you delete the `extension SunPosition.Results` (Note 1)? You have to

Comment: Yes, I deleted the extension

Comment: Then go back to the version without `&formatted=0` and decode the strings.

Comment: Decode the strings? Do you mean that I need to return extensions? Or change the type of Date from String

Comment: No, change the types back from `Date` / `TimeInterval` to `String` and remove `&formatted=0`

Comment: now I again had this error:
`Error serializing json: keyNotFound(Sunrise_Sunset.SunPosition.Results.(CodingKeys in _B4291256871B16D8D013EC8806040532).solarNoon, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Sunrise_Sunset.SunPosition.(CodingKeys in _B4291256871B16D8D013EC8806040532).results], debugDescription: "No value associated with key solarNoon (\"solarNoon\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: **For the last time**, change `enum CodingKey:String, Swift.CodingKey {` to `enum CodingKeys :String, CodingKey {`. Please copy and paste the line. It's **CodingKeys** not *CodingKey* and without `Swift.`

Comment: Okey, now everything works) Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @vadian I was having an issue while parsing my model so I used  enum CodingKey:String, Swift.CodingKey and It solved my problem. If possible can you please tell me what is happening here?

Comment: @ShanuSingh `Swift.CodingKey` is syntactic sugar. You don't need the `Swift.` prefix, `CodingKey` is sufficient especially if you declare the enum `private` as recommended

Comment: @vadian I did something like this **enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case liveStream = "live_stream" }** but it was throwing decodable error, so after looking at your answer I did this **enum CodingKey: String, Swift.CodingKey {
        case liveStream = "live_stream"
    }** , after your last comment suggestion I tried but it showing me an error **Multiple enum raw types 'String' and 'WowzaModel.CodingKey'**

Comment: @ShanuSingh Then you are using a third-party library which violates the namespace. And to convert *snaked_cased* keys to *camelCased* properties use the `.convertFromSnakeCase` strategy which makes the coding keys obsolete. And – once again – `CodingKeys` are supposed to be declared `private`.

Answer (score 1):

To rule it out, if for some reason your endpoint is returning an error message or nil data, you'll get this error.